# Перевести массив из одного вида в другой

Tags: php, массивы

jQeury плагин собирает файлы (один или несколько) из формы и отправляет на сервер вот в таком виде:

```
Array
(
    [files] => Array
        (
            [name] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 9.jpg
                    [1] => 20ebee_orig.jpg
                )

            [type] => Array
                (
                    [0] => image/jpeg
                    [1] => image/jpeg
                )

            [tmp_name] => Array
                (
                    [0] => /tmp/phpS9olDU
                    [1] => /tmp/phpFSwT6A
                )

            [error] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 0
                    [1] => 0
                )

            [size] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 59329
                    [1] => 106334
                )

        )

)
```

Как-то можно обработать на стороне сервера этот массив и привести его к вот такому виду (php 7+)?

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => 9.jpg
            [type] => image/jpeg
            [tmp_name] => /tmp/php4VNlCO
            [error] => 0
            [size] => 59329
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => 20ebee_orig.jpg
            [type] => image/jpeg
            [tmp_name] => /tmp/phpw4pTIR
            [error] => 0
            [size] => 106334
        )

)
```

Comment: Делаете цикл (foreach) в цикле и там собираете как нужно.

Comment: @MAX спасибо за комментарий. Я примерно так и предполагал, но с foreach 1 раз дело имел (могу максимум второй вариант массива разобрать). Можете показать, как в данной ситуации цикл собрать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Один из вариантов решения можно записать так:

```
$arr = Array(
    'files' => Array(
        'name' => Array(
            '9.jpg',
            '20ebee_orig.jpg'
        ),

        'type' => Array(
            'image/jpeg',
            'image/jpeg'
        ),

        'tmp_name' => Array(
            '/tmp/phpS9olDU',
            '/tmp/phpFSwT6A'
        ),

        'error' => Array(
            0,
            0
        ),

        'size' => Array(
            59329,
            106334
        )
    )
);

$result = [];

foreach ($arr as $values) {
    $keys = array_keys($values);
    $vals = array_values($values);

    do {
        foreach ($keys as $i => $key) {
            $temp[$key] = array_shift($vals[$i]);
        }
        $result[] = $temp;
    } while (! empty($vals[$i]));
}

var_dump($result);
```

Результат:

```
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    array (size=5)
      'name' => string '9.jpg' (length=5)
      'type' => string 'image/jpeg' (length=10)
      'tmp_name' => string '/tmp/phpS9olDU' (length=14)
      'error' => int 0
      'size' => int 59329
  1 => 
    array (size=5)
      'name' => string '20ebee_orig.jpg' (length=15)
      'type' => string 'image/jpeg' (length=10)
      'tmp_name' => string '/tmp/phpFSwT6A' (length=14)
      'error' => int 0
      'size' => int 106334
```